# Android get selected text on touch selection

Tags: javascript, android, events, touch

I tried to get selected text in android on selection.It is not working in touch devices. But it is working fine in normal browsers.

```
if(!window.Kolich) {
   Kolich = {};
}
Kolich.Selector = {};
// getSelected() was borrowed from CodeToad at
// http://www.codetoad.com/javascript_get_selected_text.asp
Kolich.Selector.getSelected = function() {
   var t = '';
   if(window.getSelection) {
      t = window.getSelection();
   }
   else if(document.getSelection) {
      t = document.getSelection();
   }
   else if(document.selection){
      t =document.selection.createRange().text;
   }
   return t;
}
Kolich.Selector.mouseup = function(e){
   var st = Kolich.Selector.getSelected();
   alert(st);
}
```

But Android touch selection not working with this code.. please help

Comment: Not working how? I imagine by the time `mouseup` fires in a touch browser, any previous selection may have been been destroyed by the touch. Furthermore, for any Android browser and indeed any current browser except IE <= 8, all you need to get the selected text is `window.getSelection().toString()`. That codetoad example is terrible (inconsistent return values: in some browsers it's a Selection object, in others a string) and I'm not sure how it became so popular.

Comment: Mouseup event is not triggering in android text selection

Comment: No, I wouldn't expect it to. In recent-ish WebKit browsers (including, I think, the default browser in recent Android versions), there's a `selectionchange` event that fires on `document`. Perhaps that's what you want?

Comment: I want to get the selected text in alert in text selection event(javascript) ...FYI Iam new to android development,Iam UI developer.

Answer (score 0):

Recent WebKit browsers, including the default browser in recent versions of Android, support a `selectionchange` event on `Document` nodes. This event doesn't exist in Opera or Mozilla (but has existed in IE since version 5.5).

Example code:

```
document.onselectionchange = function() {
    alert( window.getSelection().toString() );
};
```

Comment: I wouldn't have just asserted this without testing, but I don't have an Android device handy to test it now.