# javascript - code works in regular Windows's IE11 but not in WP's IE11

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8.1, internet-explorer-11

This is piece of code from bookmarklet that I have in IE11. It supposes to pop up an alert box containing the text that you select or highlight in a page. It works as expected in desktop windows' IE11 but in WP's IE11 the alert box gives me blank message. Any idea why this happens and how I can fix it for WP's IE11?

```
javascript:(function(){var text="";if(document.getSelection){alert(document.getSelection().toString());}})();
```

Comment: Might be because not every browser supports JavaScript bookmarklets.

Comment: I don't think so because all my other js bookmarklets including the complex ones, work just fine in WP's IE11, except for this one

Comment: It seems that this is not IE specific problem but web browsers on touch device as general http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628923/android-get-selected-text-on-touch-selection

Comment: That's what I meant; sorry I didn't clarify. Yeah, maybe they won't work on touch devices because of security issues.